# javascript div children do not work

Tags: javascript, html

With the yrss library, I am loading a RSS feed into my HTML document. This works.

[image: working html]

But then I want to access the divs from my JavaScript.

I can lookup the parent node (var test) and put it in the console. But when I want to get the number of child elements, it returns 0.

I'm using the following code:

```
var test = document.querySelector('#History_0');
console.log("test:");
console.log(test); //Returns <div class="item_trackHistory rss-feed" id="History_0">
console.log("test.childElementCount:");
console.log(test.childElementCount); //Returns 0
```

However, I can see the child elements I want to access in the inspector.

[image: browser infos]

Why is it that I can see the children of the `#History_0-div` in Developer Tools, but the attribute `childElementCount` returns 0?

How can I access an element's children in JavaScript?

---

Sorry for making mistakes in the way I edited my question the first time. 
here is the entire function call. I also entered the suggested solution from below. Unfortunately, it didn't work out.

`code`

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.results.length ; i++ ){
                var div = "History_" + i
                getRSS(div ,obj.results[i].feedUrl, i);
            }
```

`code`

```
this.getRSS = function(div, link, iteration){
           $('#'+div+'').yrss(link,{
           limit: 50,
        dateformat: 'localedate',
        tags:'true',
        logging:'false'
       });

    var parent = document.querySelector('#History_'+iteration+'');
    var childCount = 0;

    if (parent !== null){
        var childElements = parent.getElementsByClassName('entry-wrapper');

        console.log(childElements);
        console.log(childElements.item(0));

        if(childElements !== null){

            childCount = childElements.length;
            console.log(childCount);

        }
    }
```

The console.log of ChildElements Returns a HTML Collection, which appears to have 20 entries. But console logging the ChildElement.item(0), it Returns a null.
The console log of childCount Returns 0.

Does anyone have an idea, how it is possible to access the childElements?
Where in my entire js-file should I call a function to Access the divs, that the yrss function creates?

Comment: Probably because they are inserted after your code runs. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please include all code as _text_ in your question, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best question as others have pointed out, however, some simple things we can look at. I am unsure if the page loads the RSS feed after the page has loaded or not. I presume not, and will answer it presuming exactly that.

You can see my working code example here:
https://codepen.io/vincentritter/pen/vJmBrd?editors=1010

I've added notes too. Here is the snippet that should be the most important to get you started.

```
// Grab 'parent' div - History_0 or by class name 'rss-feed'
var parent = document.querySelector('.rss-feed');
var childCount = 0; // Just want to spit this out on the page so you can see.
// Check if parent isn't null
if(parent !== null){
  // Get child elements by class name
  var childElements = parent.getElementsByClassName('entry-wrapper');
  // Check if child elements isn't null...
  if(childElements !== null){
    // Print results, just so we can look.
    childCount = childElements.length;
    console.log(childCount);

  }
}
```

I used your images as reference.

To note, I grab stuff by their class name. Just find that easier. But everyone is different, whatever works for you.

That should get you going at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Vincent.

Unfourtunatetly, it did not quite work out. I updated my original question above, so you can see more Code. Do you have an idea, where I should place your Code snippet to Access the child divs?